# CursorLine and NonText / SpecialKey highlight clash

Tags: vim

With `:set cursorline` and `:set list`, the characters in the `NonText` and `SpecialKey` highlight groups (for example, `$` at the end of each line, and `^M` produced by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) lose their highlighting when the cursor is on the same line, reverting to the `Normal` highlight group like any other bland text. This is very confusing and ugly and bad.

These are the relevant highlights in my config:

```
:hi Conceal      term=reverse    cterm=none      ctermfg=237     ctermbg=none
:hi CursorLine   term=underline  cterm=none      ctermfg=none    ctermbg=235
:hi NonText      term=reverse    cterm=none      ctermfg=237     ctermbg=none
:hi Normal       term=none       cterm=none      ctermfg=252     ctermbg=234
:hi SpecialKey   term=reverse    cterm=none      ctermfg=14      ctermbg=23
```

The problem persists no matter my highlight configuration (including no configuration at all). I know that some highlight groups just always trump others, but syntax highlighting and highlighting from other groups (`Conceal`, for example) remains intact; is there a way to make `NonText` and `SpecialKey` retain their highlight?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, no. Bram Moolenaar [has said](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/15511) the following on this matter:

> There is no solution. [...] The cursorline highlighting needs to overrule the syntax highlighting, otherwise it would disappear in several situations, esp. if the syntax highlighting uses background highlighting.

Comment: Is it not possible to make one of the background/foreground highlighting take priority?

Comment: But, most if not all other syntax highlighting groups are unaffected; only the special characters are overridden. I'd understand if it were uniform, eg the cursorline replaced all syntax highlighting with the Normal group, but it doesn't, and your answer implies that it is all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to highlight the line number that the cursor is on you can use

```
hi CursorLineNr  term=underline  cterm=none      ctermfg=none    ctermbg=235
hi CursorLine    term=NONE cterm=NONE
```

(vim8)